# Masonry div auto-positioning

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, position, jquery-masonry, masonry

### PROBLEM

I'm not sure how to make the divs to auto-position themselves instead of leaving large blocks of space where a div can go into. I would like if the divs under the first and second divs would be directly underneath. The current markup & stylesheet is shown below. Any help on this would be great! Thank you! You can see the effect by copy-and-pasting the css and html in the respective input text fields at http://codepen.io/pen/.

```
# main.css

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item 
{
  width:  20em;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  background-color:rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 0.5em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: large;
  padding: 0.5em;
}



<!DOCTYPE html />
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.min.js" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div class="masonry">
            <div class="item">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### SOLUTION

I first deleted the invalid javascript link in the header and moved it as a script reference at the end of the the body tag. I changed the `<div class="masonry">` to `<div id="masonry">` in my HTML page. I then referenced the jquery library as well as a custom javascript file in which I have created a Masonry instance. Please see the answer post for a snippet!

I'll leave the problem & solution here just in case anyone new to masonry (like myself) gets stuck when he/she is first trying it out.

Comment: No codepen linked (empty), There's a grid-sizer and a gutter-sizer missing. Look at the docs. Use images loaded, provide examples with actual content represented. Compare the difference between examples of Masonry and Packery, you might be thinking of Packery.

Comment: Thanks Christina! I have updated the problem, as I have figured out the solution. I have also posted an answer with a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is shown below the problem in the question post. Below is the copy of the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var masonryContainer = document.querySelector('#masonry');
    var masonry = new Masonry(masonryContainer, {
        // options
        itemSelector: '.item'
    });
});
```

```css
.item 
{
  width:  20em;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  background-color:rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 0.5em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: large;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div id="masonry">
            <div class="item">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```